# TextBox and ComboBox validation not working as intended

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, combobox

I want to validate multiple `TextBoxes` and `Comboboxes` with a `MessageBox`. I have done that, but the problem now is that once I fill `Jtextbox3`and `ComboBox1` it ignores the other `TextBoxes` and`ComboBoxes` and goes to the next form.

Here is my code:

```
private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    userform3 form3 = new userform3();
    var jtextboxes = new[] { jTextBox3, jTextBox4, jTextBox5, jTextBox6, jTextBox7, jTextBox8, jTextBox9, jTextBox10, jTextBox11, jTextBox12, jTextBox13, jTextBox14, jTextBox15, };
    var comboboxes = new[] { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3, comboBox4, comboBox5, comboBox6 };
    foreach (var jbox in jtextboxes)
    {
        foreach (var combo in comboboxes)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jbox.TextValue) || combo.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "", "Please Enter All the Fields as Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
            else
            {
                form3.Show();
                this.Hide();
                form3.Hide();
                form3.ShowDialog();
                this.Show();
            }

            break;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kvuo.png) is the form. I have marked the `TextBox` and `ComboBox` that I have a problem with.

Comment: try returning after your metro message box

Comment: @Clint it didnt work :(

Comment: as sr28 mentioned, those breaks are unncessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only checking the first `TextBox` and the first `ComboBox`. You have a `break` statement at the end of both `foreach` loops, so each loop will only execute one time... in other words you're only ever validating the first item in `jtextboxes` and `comboboxes`.

Furthermore, the inner loop is written in such a way that the code hiding / showing the forms will execute as soon as you encounter a `TextBox` with a value and a `ComboBox` with a value. A different way to write this might be:

```csharp
private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    userform3 form3 = new userform3();
    var jtextboxes = new[] { jTextBox3, jTextBox4, jTextBox5, jTextBox6, jTextBox7, jTextBox8, jTextBox9, jTextBox10, jTextBox11, jTextBox12, jTextBox13, jTextBox14, jTextBox15, };
    var comboboxes = new[] { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3, comboBox4, comboBox5, comboBox6 };
    if (jtextboxes.Any(tb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.TextValue)) || comboboxes.Any(cb => cb.SelectedItem == null))
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "", "Please Enter All the Fields as Required", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
    else
    {
        form3.Show();
        this.Hide();
        form3.Hide();
        form3.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

This will show the message box if any of the `TextBox`es are empty, or if any of the `ComboBox`es don't have a selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your 'break' in the wrong place for both the foreach loops. Break means that it will break out of the loop. So in your code, you're breaking out of the inner foreach loop after Combobox1 and then breaking out of the outer foreach after your first textbox. Remove those and it should work fine

Comment: i just removed both breaks, nothing different